# How to make instant noodle with egg?

Tags: eggs, noodles

I made instant noodle, just put the noodle into boiling water for about 3 minutes, and noodle is already. But this time I want make this with an egg, how? should I break the egg first and then put the egg into a boiling water for a minutes then I put the noodle or vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a student in Singapore, we often eat instant noodles because we tend to be lazy and we lack the time to cook.

So here's how i usually do my instant noodles.

Always make sure the water is boiling hot that it bubbles rapidly. Next, you can just put your noodle in. Add the seasoning on the top of the noodles because if large amount of seasoning comes in contact with boiling water, the water bubbles out of the pot easily.

Eggs by itself, do not necessary need a hot boiling water, as long as the water is hot, it will still cook by itself.

Usually, i will place my egg about 1.5 minute later near the bubbling area (that is the hottest part of the pot) and let it boil for 20 second before offing the flames. Hence, i'll get my perfect half-cooked eggs with my favourite instant noodles.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you're adding the water to the noodles or vice versa.

If I'm boiling the noodles on the stove for three minutes, I measure the right amount of water, and after the noodles are cooked I usually lift (most) of the noodles out of the water and into the bowl, drop the egg in and let it cook in the water while I add the seasoning to the noodles, then pour the egg (and as much water as I want) into the bowl.  I tend to lift the noodles out because they splash more when pouring, but no reason you couldn't add the egg to the noodles and water straight after they're cooked, or even during cooking.  If you do you add the egg as soon as the stove is turned off, the residual heat in the water cooks it enough.  If you don't want extra water in your noodles, you can lift it out with a slotted spoon, or pour most of the water out first, then add to your noodles.

If I'm pouring boiling water onto the noodles (already in the bowl), I add the egg first, even break the yolk and stir a little, lay the noodles on top, and pour the boiling water.  In this case, the water will cool too much to cook the egg fairly fast, so it needs to be there from the start, and almost scrambled to cook more evenly.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried many ways of making egg noodles.
I suggest to boil the noodles first with all the necessary ingredients and keep it aside.Then beat eggs in a vessel .Heat frying pan.Add oil.Add finely chopped onions and greenchillies and a pinch of salt.Wait till onions impart a brown colour.To this add beated eggs and fry continously stirring.Mix this to your noodles.Serve hot.The egg wil remain crispier and tastier if done this way